# Searching map/reduce view with keys of arrays

Tags: cloudant

I have map/reduced view as
emit([doc.State, doc.City, doc.ZipCode.toString()], [doc.TotalLoadWeight]);

I want to search it using keys ex Key=["Arizona", "Chandler"].
This works if my key is single. But incase of arrrays is searching possible?

Comment: Sample output i am getting

Comment: key: [
"Arizona",
"Chandler",
"85225"
],

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use multiple keys in your search you should use the `keys` parameter which takes a JSON Array, so you'd then have: `keys=[["Arizona", "Chandler"],["xxx", "yyy"]` The view will then return all entries with keys which match either `["Arizona", "Chandler"]` or `["xxx", "yyy"]`